# Checking if a string is present as an element in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

What's the most efficient way to check whether an stl vector of strings contains 
a specific string?

Comment: If checking for the presence of an item in your container is something you plan on having to do often, you might want to consider using a std::set instead (providing of course that you don't want duplicate strings in your set). std::set has a find() method for which average complexity is guaranteed to be log(n).

Answer (score 20):

The obvious yet possibly too-slow solution is `std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), your_string);`

If your vector isn't changing much, sort it first, then use `binary_search`, `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, or `equal_range`. If your vector changes a lot, consider using a `set`/`multiset` (or if needed `map`/`multimap`) instead.

Depending on your needs a hash (`unordered_set`) might be appropriate as well, but it's more different from your initial container choice than normal ordered containers, and not supplied prior to C++0x (you can get it from boost easily).

Comment: Or a `multiset` if the value may exist more than once.

Comment: Faster still might be a hash-table, or a prefix tree (aka trie). The former is more-or-less standard: `unordered_set` in C++0x (also available in Boost), or `hash_set` in old-school STL. You might have to write your own version of the latter, or search for a good implementation.

Answer (score 10):

Use `std::find` to find the target string.  This is a linear search, so beware searching large vectors.

To find out if the vector contains the target or not, use:

```
bool isPresent = (std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), target) != vec.end());
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a C++11 alternative:

```
#include<functional>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

std::vector<std::string> v;
bool elementFound = std::any_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::string const& s) {return s=="string-to-search";});
```

Feel free to adjust the lambda function to what you want, e.g.

```
[](std::string const& s) {return s.size()>3;}
```

Comment: There are specific algorithms for this within the STL. Why use a generic lamda for it when there is a better alternative?

Comment: Because (i) as mentioned, it's extendable, (ii) obtaining a bool is imo nicer than questioning iterators and (iii) it's an alternative to the other 4 answer which all state the same concept ... I didn't say it is the most efficient one.

Comment: Ok, I just recognized that the question explicitly asked for efficiency. As said, I don't know how it behaves compared to `std::find`, but still it might be useful.

Comment: Actually this has helped me even though it was inefficient for OP's case.

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<string> v;
vector<string>::iterator it;
it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), "stringToFind");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use std::find to find the string.

```
std::find(stringVector.begin(), stringVector.end(), "specificStringToFind") ;
```